# Getting a full screen image in projection mode for PowerPoint 2013 on a Dell Latitude laptop

Tags: laptop, microsoft-powerpoint, fullscreen

Pretty strange.  I have a 16x9 PowerPoint presentation. In presentation mode it takes up the full screen on my laptop.  However, when I hit F8 to project (even with no projector connected) the image is reduced and there are black bars all the way around the image.

Comment: F8 or F5 key? Because I don't see any action assigned to F8 key in Power Point 2013 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Slide Show | Set Up Slide Show

Under "Resolution" verify that it's set to Use Current Resolution or a resolution that matches your screen rez.

Sounds like it might be set to some other resolution.